# AngularJS Directive for specific tag name

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

How can I force specific tag for a directive in AngularJS?

For example, I want to create a directive that will be applied only on `<img>` tags. If the user put this directive on a `<div>`, I don't want the directive to be active. How can I do that?

Comment: You want a custom tag for your directive, right?

Comment: @Sebastian: No. I am sorry, but there was a mistake in the question. Now it is fixed.

Comment: Why not make the directive work with both? You could insert an img tag when the source element is not an image (assumes they supply relevant data attributes to your directive) , otherwise if the source elem is an  image just operate on it directly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have 2 options.

**#1** Use your existing directive that you have working and add a couple lines

code:

```
link: function(scope,element,attr) {

    if (element[0].tagName== 'IMG') {
        //do your stuff
    } else {
        // do nothing or something else
    }
}
```

---

**#2** Restrict your directive to be just an element (as shown in Fizer Khan's answer).

```
.directive('myIMG', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      templateUrl: 'img.html',//essentially has <img src=''>
      template: "<img src='scope.path'>",//build out your image tag here which will replace the HTML the directive is on
      transclude: true,
      scope: {
          path: '='
      },
      link: function(scope, element, attr) {

      }
    };
  });
```

HTML

```
<myIMG path=''></myIMG>
```

I personally like option 2 best. But I know that can be more daunting, and often introduces other unexpected things.

Comment: I wouldn't recomend you do this, as older browsers (and more important, crawlers) might not understand correctly that this is an img which might bring you some headaches.

Comment: One small adjustment I like for this is to use `if ( element[ 0 ].tagName !== "A" ) return;` instead of the empty `else {}` statement.

Answer (score 4):

## Simplest approach

#### Define directive of specific HTML tag

Even though this question has been asked long ago there's no answer that creates directive on the required element itself. So here's another possible way of defining an Angular directive that restricts itself to `IMG` tags

```
appModule
    .directive("img", function() {
        restrict: "E",
        link: function(scope, element, attributes) {
            if (!element.hasClass("something") && !attributes.something)
            {
                // just a normal image
                return;
            }

            // do your stuff
        }
    });
```

This code defines a directive for `IMG` element but when it initializes it checks that there's either a specific CSS class and/or HTML attribute defined on it. If it doesn't have any, it gracefully exits as this image should not be *directed*. But if any of those is defined on it, it does its thing.

## Best approach

#### Two directives on the same element with requirements

The following is likely the best possible Angular approach to this. IT consists of two directives. One that is on the `img` element and the other that is an attribute/class directive and requires `img` directive.

```
appModule
    .directive("img", function() {
        restrict: "E",
        controller: function imgController() {
            // does nothing really
        }
    })
    .directive("imgSpecific", function() {
        restrict: "AC",
        require: "img",
        link: function() {
            // do your stuff
        }
    });
```

So the second directive actually requires an `img` directive which is restrictive to image elements on the same element and if present, then this directive will actually run, otherwise it will produce a runtime exception as its requirements aren't met.

By doing it this way, both directives will be very simple without any specific code that checks certain conditions for the directive to actually execute. All this checks are already done within Angular code and our directives (the second/child one specifically) will only execute on image elements when both are present.

Comment: Doesn't `restrict: "AC"` already cause the directive to not trigger as an element? Also the question was how you could limit it to a specific tag and I don't see how this code would do that. If I'm mistaken pleas clear things up for me.

Comment: @Aides: The OP asked how could they restrict their directive to `IMG` elements so instead of creating an attribute/class directive of their directive I've written a directive that is applied to image elements directly that checks whether specific custom attributes are present in which case it should do its work. **But I had a bug**. I've invalidly restricted this directive to `AC` instead of an `E`. **Addition:** I've also added additional approach which is likely the best one as it doesn't have to check any conditions for the `AC` directive to execute. It will run on `img` elements only.

Answer (score 1):

You  can set `restrict` attribute to `E` in the directive

```
 restrict: 'E'
```

The tag name always be `directive` name.

**Example**

```
 angular.module('myapp', [])
.directive('myTag', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      templateUrl: 'my-tag.html',
      scope: {

      },
      link: function(scope, element, attr) {

      }
    };
  });
```

Only way to use this directive is

```
<my-tag></mytag>
```

Comment: This is not what I meant. There was a mistake in my question and I fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Id suggest you support both approaches, as Angular does not restrict to element tag name.
It seems to come down to how you want to handle what, in your design, is a user error.
The user should only ever use your directive on an img element so what do you want to
do when they dont follow your intentions? If you want to handle the error gracefully and continue then
insert an img for them and proceeed.

http://plnkr.co/edit/RCS8uZgPFx2VgxQv73A4?p=preview

```
<html>

<head>
<script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.2.16" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
<script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<img src="http://www.w3.org/html/logo/img/badge-samples.png" img-test>
<div data-src="http://www.w3.org/html/logo/img/badge-samples.png" img-test></div>
<script>

  var app=angular.module("app",[]);

  app.directive("imgTest",function(){
    var link=function(scope,elem,attrs){
      var img;
      if(elem.tagName !="IMG"){
        img=document.createElement("img");
        img.setAttribute("src",attrs.src);
        elem.append(img);
      }
    };

    return{
      "link" : link
    }
  });

  angular.bootstrap(document,["app"]);

</script>
```